# Accessing variables of one function within another function

Tags: c++, function

I am trying to create a batching function that calls other functions. One of these functions creates a vector to be used in some other functions within the batching function.

Below is the simplified code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class A{
    private:
        int k;
    public:
        void Batch(char* argv[]);
        void Create(int const &N);
        int Search(int const &key);
        //more functions

}
void A::Batch(char** argv){
    int size 100;
    std::string bat_cmd;
    if(bat_cmd == "0"){
        Create(size);
    }
    else if(bat_cmd == "1"){
        Search(k);
    }
}
void A::Create(int const &N){
    //This is where I am stuck
}
int A::Search(int const &key){
    for(auto i: vec){
        if(i == key)
            return i;
        else
            return -1;
    }
}

    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    A a;
    a.Batch(argv);
    
}
```

If I initialize a vector inside of the Create function, how do I access that vector within one of the other functions? I tried to make the vector a private variable within the Class A, but that didn't really help. If anyone has any hints on a better way to do this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Functions communicate through:

- Inputs: arguments to the function.
- Output: the return value of the function.
- External variables: either "global" variables, or member variables, when the function is a member function of a class/struct.

Comment: Ok, I understand thanks. I think I know what I would need to do to make this work.